# How do I encode the secret for the 'create-passenger-name-record-sample-nodejs' Sabre API example?

Tags: token, sabre

I'm trying to run the 'create-passenger-name-record-sample-nodejs' example code. It requires a secret and PCC as shown below:

```
  endpoint: 'https://api.test.sabre.com',
  secret: process.env.SWS_API_SECRET || '',
  pcc: process.env.SWS_API_PCC || '',
};
```

According to the documentation, the secret above is a base64 encoding of 'V1:userid:group:domain'.
I have created an account but it is not clear to me where to obtain the pieces necessary to construct the concatenated string above and also where to obtain the PCC.

Is anyone able to provide some guidance?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

_Username and password should be provided by your account executive if you have a Sabre subscription. If you do not have a Sabre subscription, you should be able to obtain sample credentials to test in test environments. You can find your test credentials under "Applications" when you click on "My account". The procedure to encode a token, if needed, is located at https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/developer-guides/rest-apis-token-credentials.

Comment: I've seen that procedure previously and followed it with no success. I have sample credentials and I see 'Client ID' & 'Client Secret'. What is the relationship between those 2 values and the procedure to encode a token?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to base64 encode the ClientID. Then base64 encode the ClientSecret. Then join those results with a ':' and base64 encode the joined string. This then is used as the value of the 'secret' field in the JSON snippet above.